# OrmLiteConfigUtil config file generation problems

Tags: android, ormlite

I raised this as a [bug on the ORMLite Sourceforge bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/bugs/158/) but I haven't seen any updates.  I didn't see any process docs saying if I need to do anything to pass it to Gray?

Seen testing v4.47 (the behaviour on older ORMLite versions is worse as the config file generation fails much earlier).

My @DatabaseTable classes all include some Android imports, e.g.

```
import android.content.Context;
```

Most of my classes extend a single abstract superclass, e.g.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = SongMessage.TABLE_NAME)
public class SongMessage extends AbstractMessage {
```

However, a few of my classes extend a shared abstract super class, e.g.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = PhotoMessage.TABLE_NAME)
public class PhotoMessage extends SingleImageMessage implements <snip> {
```

SingleImageMessage extends the same common AbstractMessage:

```
public abstract class SingleImageMessage extends AbstractMessage {
```

Running my OrmLiteConfigUtil works fine for my direct subclasses, but doesn't work for the ones which extend the intermediate abstract class:

```
...
Wrote config for class com.mypackage.TextMessage
Skipping class com.mypackage.PhotoMessage because we got an error finding its definition: android/content/Context
Wrote config for class com.mypackage.SongMessage
...
```

Comment: My question has nothing to do with yours. I am just curious why do you need android Context in the model?

Comment: In this specific case, I have a getDisplayPreview(Context) method that is different for each message type.  Some of the message types use localized text resources, which require a Context to retrieve them.  I could remove the Context parameter, but in that case I'd then need to get a Context locally, which would still require the import.  I also use LayoutParams and Bitmap in some of my message types, although those uses could be more easily refactored out.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late reply.  ORMLite has been a bit swapped out as of late.

> Running my OrmLiteConfigUtil works fine for my direct subclasses, but doesn't work for the ones which extend the intermediate abstract class:

This problem is obviously because of the `Context` import. Unfortunately the OrmLiteConfigUtil is running locally and does not have access to that class which is only exported as a stub by Google.

One thing that I could do is just catch and log an error only when the *superclass* cannot be investigated.  So the subclass would be outputted correctly.  Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I may need to see more of your abstract class definition. The error, may be coming from the DatabaseFieldConfig.fromField call. The error message indicates that it's trying to find a database type definition for android.content.Context. Is there a field declared in your abstract class that is of that type? Here's the code that produces the error message you're seeing.

```
    private static void writeConfigForTable(BufferedWriter writer, Class<?> clazz) throws SQLException, IOException {
    String tableName = DatabaseTableConfig.extractTableName(clazz);
    List<DatabaseFieldConfig> fieldConfigs = new ArrayList<DatabaseFieldConfig>();
    // walk up the classes finding the fields
    try {
        for (Class<?> working = clazz; working != null; working = working.getSuperclass()) {
            for (Field field : working.getDeclaredFields()) {
                DatabaseFieldConfig fieldConfig = DatabaseFieldConfig.fromField(databaseType, tableName, field);
                if (fieldConfig != null) {
                    fieldConfigs.add(fieldConfig);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Error e) {
        System.err.println("Skipping " + clazz + " because we got an error finding its definition: "
                + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    if (fieldConfigs.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Skipping " + clazz + " because no annotated fields found");
        return;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    DatabaseTableConfig<?> tableConfig = new DatabaseTableConfig(clazz, tableName, fieldConfigs);
    DatabaseTableConfigLoader.write(writer, tableConfig);
    writer.append("#################################");
    writer.newLine();
    System.out.println("Wrote config for " + clazz);
}
```

Comment: Where does the documentation for getSuperclass say about the InstantiationException?  I can't see it...

Comment: You're right. The exception I noted was related to another method in the same body of text. I've updated my answer. Have you tried removing any references to the android.content.Context class to see if the error persists? And if that isn't fruitful, I may, in your shoes, add the OrmLite sources to my project and step through them. It's ugly, but you can be sure it would help you understand the issue.